# How to switch 1 (ON) flags occurring together in batch of size more than a specified threshold to 0 in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

A flag column in a pandas dataframe is populated by `1` or `0`

The problem is to identify continuous `1`s.

Let `t` be the number of days thresholds
There are two types of transformations required:
 i) If there are more than t 1s together, turn the `(t+1)th` onwards 1 to 0
ii) If there are more than t 1s together, turn all the 1s to 0s

My approach is to create 2 columns called `result1` and `result2`, and filter using these columns:

[Please see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BAEL.jpg)

I have not been able to think of anything as such, so not posting any code.
**A nudge or hint in the right direction would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#compare 0 values
m = df['Value'].eq(0)
#get cumulative sum and filter only 1 rows
g = m.cumsum()[~m]

#set by condition - 0 or ccounter per groups
df['Result1'] = np.where(m, 0, df.groupby(g).cumcount().add(1))
#get maximum per groups with transform for new Series
df['Result2'] = np.where(m, 0, df.groupby(g)['Result1'].transform('max')).astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
    Value  Result1  Result2
0       1        1        1
1       0        0        0
2       0        0        0
3       1        1        2
4       1        2        2
5       0        0        0
6       1        1        4
7       1        2        4
8       1        3        4
9       1        4        4
10      0        0        0
11      0        0        0
12      1        1        1
13      0        0        0
14      1        1        1
15      0        0        0
16      0        0        0
17      1        1        6
18      1        2        6
19      1        3        6
20      1        4        6
21      1        5        6
22      1        6        6
23      0        0        0
24      1        1        1
25      0        0        0
26      0        0        0
27      1        1        1
28      0        0        0
```